# FXML include in Java?

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8, fxml

```
<Tab fx:id="usersFXML" text="Employees">
    <content>
        <fx:include source="users/main.fxml" />
    </content>
</Tab>
```

How can I create a tab like that in JavaFX?

I have the following:

```
Tab employeeTab = new Tab("Employees"); 
tabPane.getTabs().add(employeeTab);
```

I know that I might have to use `employeeTab.setContent()` but I have no idea how to do add the include `<fx:include source="users/main.fxml" />` in `employeeTab.setContent()`.

Comment: Just use a `FXMLLoader` in the usual way.

Comment: @James_D could you perhaps give me an example of it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just load the FXML file in the usual way:

```
Tab employeeTab = new Tab("Employees");
tab.setContent(FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getResource("users/main.fxml")));
tabPane.getTabs().add(employeeTab);
```

You may need to modify the path to get it correct (I don't know your project layout).